# transfer my laptops recovery partition keeping it bootable

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have an Acer aspire 5750 laptop which initially stopped booting but I placed the hdd into another pc and chkdsk managed to fix it enough to get it booting. Sadly it still resets when certain parts of the main partition are accessed. I want to transfer the recovery partition to a new 1TB Hard drive and then use it to reset to factory default windows 7 installation on the new drive.

OLD DRIVE:
    Main partion (broken) 496 GB (bootable)
    Recovery partion 15 GB
    Other partitioon 100meg

I have tried to duplicate the whole drive or backup the whole drive but the process fails and causes a reset, so my plan is to transfer the partition with the "return to factory default " software on it and then boot from that drive to reinstate the default system.

I have tried driveimage xml but it gives errors about drive locking and fails before finishing . So I am using Seagate's tool / wizard. (Is there more versatile software you can recommend?)

If I could some how copy the recovery partition and the boot recovery menu, that would be enough,but only I seem to be able to copy the partition and do not get the boot menu / recovery menu .

Comment: Tool i used to solve this problem were

Easy BCDEDIT 2.2
Seagate drive WIZARD
dRIVEIMAGExml